# Cross compile Static Library from Linux for windows

Tags: c, linux

I want to compile static library in linux for windows. Following is the procedure I followed for compiling

1. Compile the source code of static library in linux using `i586-mingw32msvc-cc  -c static_lib.c -o static_lib.o`
2. Created the static library in linux `ar rv static_lib.a static_lib.o` and `ranlib static_lib.a`
3. I created a sample program in eclipse on windows and linked this static library which is cross compiled in linux for windows. The compiler used at windows was mingw.

while compiling the program in windows eclipse, the compiler gives me the following error.

```
static_test\static_lib.a: file format not recognized; treating as linker script 
\static_test\static_lib.a:1: syntax error
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Build error occurred, build is stopped
```

The Codes are as follows:

static_lib.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(void)
{
        printf("Hello\n");
        printf("Hello\n");
        printf("Hello\n");
        printf("Hello\n");
        printf("Hello\n");
        printf("Hello\n");
        printf("Hello\n");
        printf("Hello\n");
        printf("Hello\n");
        printf("Hello\n");
        printf("Hello\n");
        printf("Hello\n");
}
```

sample_static.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern void func(void);

int main ()
{
    printf ("Main function\n");
    func();
}
```

kindly give me suggestions to compile and get it work.

Regards
Johnnie Alan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the cross-compiler archiver instead of the native one, i.e. use `i586-mingw32msvc-ar` and `i586-mingw32msvc-ranlib` instead of `ar` and `ranlib`.

Or is that just a typo on the question?

Comment: Even after using cross-compiler archiver, the mingw linker on windows throws the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Try `i586-mingw32msvc-ar` instead of plain `ar`. Typically `ar` in Linux will not support the PE format used for Windows programming. (Or you will have to instruct it to use PE format.)