# How to compile static .lib library for Windows in Linux or Macos

Tags: c, linux, windows, macos, static-libraries

I am searching way to compile static library for Windows in Linux or Macos, there seems to be cross compiler to generate .a library for Windows like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624078/cross-compile-static-library-from-linux-for-windows), but that is not what I want, what I want is  a .lib static library file for Windows, preferably for Visual Studio.  I know I can run a Windows virtual machine and using Visual Studio, but that is too heavy, and can't be done in command line.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For unix-like OSes (Linux, MacOS, etc) a *static library* means
an [`ar` archive](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ar) of object files. `ar` is the GNU general
purpose archiver. It doesn't care what kind of files you stick into an archive. It's
just the custom to call it "a static library" when they happen to be object files. And
it's also just a custom for an `ar` archive to be called `*.a`. You can call it
`*.lib`, or anything.

For Visual Studio, a *static library* means an archive of PE-format object files
usually created by the Microsoft tool [`LIB`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ykb2k5f.aspx).

The format of an Microsoft LIB archive is in fact the same as that of a Unix `ar` archive. Microsoft
just adopted it, long long ago.

So if you compile some PE object files on Linux using your distro's PE cross-compiler
then archive them into a `*.lib` with `ar`, you've got yourself a static library that's good to go in Windows
with the Visual Studio compiler.

Well, you have as long as those object files have C binary interfaces.
If any of them have C++ interfaces, they're useless: the Microsoft and GCC C++ compilers use different name-mangling protocols and are otherwise ABI incompatible.

**Demo**

We start in linux with some source code for the static library:

**hello.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void hello(void)
{
    puts("Hello world");
}
```

Cross-compile:

```
$ x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-win32 -o hello.obj -c hello.c
```

Make the static library:

```
$ ar rcs hello.lib hello.obj
```

Then a program that's going to be linked with `hello.lib`:

**main.c**

```
extern void hello(void);

int main(void)
{
    hello();
    return 0;
}
```

Now we hop into a Windows 10 VM where we're looking at the the files we've
just created through a shared folder:

```
E:\develop\so\xstatlib>dir
 Volume in drive E is VBOX_imk
 Volume Serial Number is 0000-0804

 Directory of E:\develop\so\xstatlib

03/12/2017  18:37                72 main.c
03/12/2017  18:29               978 hello.lib
03/12/2017  18:26                66 hello.c
03/12/2017  18:27               832 hello.obj
               4 File(s)          1,948 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  153,282,871,296 bytes free
```

Compile and link our program:

```
E:\develop\so\xstatlib>cl /Fehello.exe main.c hello.lib
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.11.25547 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

main.c
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.11.25547.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:hello.exe
main.obj
hello.lib
```

Run it:

```
E:\develop\so\xstatlib>hello
Hello world
```

Comment: What about `extern "C"`? Does that help with gcc/VisualStudio compatibility in regards to C++ name mangling?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Yes indeed, though of course the APIs in the scope of `extern "C"` must be valid
C APIs to begin with. I've made the wording more accurate.

Comment: Thank you so much for such detail explanation and example, much appreciated.

Comment: What about the opposite? Generate a static library which is macOS valid in Windows?

Comment: @Royi You mean [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55758704/1362568). You
simply cannot create Linux binaries with MSVC. MSVC generates Microsoft PE/COFF
format binaries. Linux binaries are ELF format. Chalk and cheese. You can only
build ELF binaries on Windows by [cross-compiling in a Unix-like
environment under Windows](http://metamod-p.sourceforge.net/cross-compiling.on.windows.for.linux.html),
or by building in a Linux VM or [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10). The answer above describes cross-compiling Linux -> Windows.