# Error while compiling Halide program using Linux command in Windows environment through Cygwin

Tags: halide

[image]
I downloaded Halide binaries for Linux. For compiling the tutorial programs(especially the autoscheduler program), I need to install g++ version 5.3. But, I am not able to install this particular version. How to solve the problem? Please find the instructions below copied from the link : https://github.com/halide/Halide/releases
[image]

**Update 1:**
I ran the command sudo apt install g++-5.3 . I got the error "Unable to locate the package g++5.3"

**Update 2:**
These are some of the errors I get.
[image]

**Update 4:**
I want to run this program :
https://halide-lang.org/tutorials/tutorial_lesson_21_auto_scheduler_generate.html.
The linux command is given at the very top of the above link. I am pasting it below:
**g++ lesson_21_auto_scheduler_generate.cpp ../tools/GenGen.cpp -g -std=c++11 -fno-rtti -I ../include -L ../bin -lHalide -lpthread -ldl -o lesson_21_generate**

Additionally, I moved the "libHalide.a" file from the lib folder to the bin folder and executed the commmand.

Comment: Just saying you "not able to" do something isn't enough for us to be able to help. You need to tell us exactly what you did, and exactly what happened when you did it.

Comment: Hi @Joseph , I have updated my question. Thank You.

Comment: `g++-5.3` is really old. Why do you think you need that specific version? What happens if you just do `sudo apt install g++` and then try installing Halide?

Comment: I get linker errors. I have updated the question with the instructions.

Comment: Please add the linker errors to the question, as well as the exact commands you ran leading up to them.

Comment: By the way, the text you quoted was from an old release. The latest release doesn't say that.

Comment: I have pasted a screenshot of some of the errors that I get.

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux? If you're on Windows, then why did you download the Linux version? If you're on Linux, then why are there references to Cygwin in the paths?

Comment: I don't how to run the program on Windows. I ran it in Visual Studio and I got build errors. It references ../tools/GenGen.cpp which has the main function. I don't how to give a similar command on Windows. So, I installed Cygwin and tried it out.

Comment: Later, I installed Virtual Box with Ubuntu. I tried installing G++-5.3 there. I got "unable to locate package error".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're on Windows, as your references to `x86_64-pc-cygwin` and `/cygdrive/c` in your screenshot indicate, but you're trying to use the Linux binaries. Cygwin is only source-compatible with Linux programs, not binary-compatible. Here's your choices:

- Use the Windows or MinGW downloads instead of the Linux ones (you may have to switch to MinGW)
- In Ubuntu in VirtualBox, just install `g++` instead of `g++-5.3`, and then use the Linux download there

Comment: Thank You. I installed VirtualBox and installed g++ and was able to execute the command without errors. I had tried executing the command after installing MinGW. But it threw some errors related to mutex. The command has -lpthreads option.

Comment: the command ( g++ lesson_21_auto_scheduler_generate.cpp ../tools/GenGen.cpp -g -std=c++11 -fno-rtti -I ../include -L ../bin -lHalide -lpthread -ldl -o lesson_21_generate) generates .a file. I need .lib file for windows environment. How can we execute this in Windows?

Comment: @anju.gopinath See [How to compile static .lib library for Windows in Linux or Macos](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47614835/7509065)

Comment: I RENAMED BOTH THE .cpp files MENTIONED IN THE COMMAND to .c AND TRIED THIS COMMAND :" x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ lesson_21.c ../tools/GenGen.c -g -std=c++11 -fno-rtti -I ../include -L ../bin -lHalide -lpthread -ldl -o lesson_21_generate.obj " I GOT THE ERROR  "/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -ldl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status"

Comment: IF I GIVE THE COMMAND : "x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-win32 lesson_21.c ../tools/GenGen.c -g -I ../include -L ../bin -lHalide -lpthread -ldl -o lesson_21_generate.obj" I GET THE ERROR
"In file included from lesson_21.c:24:
../include/Halide.h:59:10: fatal error: atomic: No such file or directory
   59 | #include <atomic>
      |          ^~~~~~~~"

Comment: Did you downgrade to an ancient GCC again? And do you have `libdl`?

Comment: Hi Joseph , I didn't downgrade the GCC. In the solution mentioned in the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47614835/how-to-compile-static-lib-library-for-windows-in-linux-or-macos , "x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-win32" is used

Comment: When I gave "x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-win32 --version" ... I got this ->
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-win32 (GCC) 9.3-win32 20200320 ... sorry for not posting pics... I am trying this out in the VirtualBox (Ubuntu)

Comment: Sigh, you're mixing up operating systems AGAIN. Either do everything on Windows and for Windows, or everything on Ubuntu and for Ubuntu. Trying to cross-compile is only going to cause you headaches

Comment: My bad . Sorry . I thought one had to execute it on Ubuntu. I will execute it on Windows. May I know how to install the libdl package please?

Comment: In the link you had posted , the description is "

I am searching way to compile static library for Windows in Linux " ... that means I am supposed to execute the command in a Linux environment right? And there I will get a .lib file and I can then use it in Windows environment. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Because I thought that's what you wanted to do, but it turned out you had no idea what you were doing.

Comment: So, I have a Windows machine. I installed Virtual Box and added Ubuntu. And inside the Virtual Box , in the Ubuntu OS, I gave the command => x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ lesson_21.c ../tools/GenGen.c -g -std=c++11 -fno-rtti -I ../include -L ../bin -lHalide -lpthread -ldl -o lesson_21_generate.obj

Comment: Since that gave me an error, I also tried x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-win32 lesson_21.c ../tools/GenGen.c -g -I ../include -L ../bin -lHalide -lpthread -ldl -o lesson_21_generate.obj. This also gave me an error

Comment: You have two choices. 1. Delete everything related to Halide inside VirtualBox, and do everything for Halide, including running it, completely on Windows. 2. Delete everything related to Halide from Windows, and do everything for Halide, including running it, completely inside VirtualBox.

Comment: `obj` files are a Windows-ism, so no.

Comment: Okay. May I know how to install libdl please? I wasn't able to find the command.